# Pyintaller , python и exe файл

Tags: python, windows, файлы, pyinstaller

Я преобразовал py файл в exe через pyinstaller. Файл который был преобразован , создаёт 7 файлов на рабочем столе . Код:

```
import sys,os
print("======TrolledByTaras======")
names = ["File1","File2","File3","File4","File5"]
howmuch = "6"
namesmore = "File"
crash = True
write = ""
while crash == True:
    result = howmuch + namesmore
    names.append(result)
    howmuch += "1"
    while len(write) < 30:
        write +="_First Virus_"
    if len(names) > 3:
        crash = False
for file in names:
    some = open(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\x\Desktop\\",file + ".txt"),"w",encoding = "utf- 8")
    with some as f:
        f.write(write)
```

Python - 3.6.Засунул этот файл в zip архив , и кинул другу что бы тот проверил её работоспособность . В итоге , файлы не создались.
Почему файлы не создались,и как это решить?P.S Все действия проходились на windows 10 и 7

Comment: А у вашего друга в системе есть пользователь x? Он проверял наличие файлов на рабочем столе именно этого пользователя?

Comment: @Александр нету,теперь можете записать это в ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй `pyinstaller myscript.py --onefile`.

*PyInstaller анализирует файл myscript.py и делает следующее:
Пишет файл myscript.spec в той же папке, где находится скрипт.
Создает папку build в той же папке, где находится скрипт.
Записывает некоторые логи и рабочие файлы в папку build.
Создает папку dist в той же папке, где находится скрипт.
Пишет исполняемый файл в папку dist.
После работы программы вы найдете две папки: dist и build. Собственно в папке dist и находится наше приложение. Впоследствии папку build можно спокойно удалить, она не влияет на работоспособность приложения.*

Comment: неужели нет программы которая делает только один exe без всяких этих заморочек